# Run Activity B from Notification and force back button to run Activity A

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android application that contains two `Activities`.

`Activity A` has a button that launches `Activity B` using `Context.startActivity(Intent intent)`.

There is also a `Notification` that opens Activity in the same way.

If I start `B` from this notification and press back button - it just closes `B` and does not shows `A` like I go there with normal case.

Is it possible to force `B` to bo back to `A` if started from notification without history stack ?

**Solution**

As **stefan** and **Paul Lammertsma** mentioned, the best way is to start `A` from notification and in `A` create new intent with `B` - but not in `onCreate()` !

I dig this a bit and found that if I set in `AndroidManifest` a new property for `A` activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

there will be in `A` activity called

```
onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

And there we should checl if `Intent` containst extra value passed from notification - and if so, then we call new `B` intent.

Thank you both and good luck with it for next devs ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest having the notification call Activity A (instead of B directly) with some flag in its extras bundle. In A's `onCreate()`, check for the flag, and immediately launch Activity B. This will ensure that pressing back on B will return to A.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to achieve this would be to actually start Activity A from your Notification with a flag to call Activity B instantly.

So you just have to put an extra to your intent you are starting in your Notification and you have to check in Activity A if this extra exists and if it exists then you start Activity B.

Update: another way, but in my opinion not so good, would be to override the onPause() method of your Activity B and call Activity A there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the prettiest solution, but nevertheless a quick one; 
add a boolean extra to the intent launching *B*, "launchedFromNotification" or something like that.
In activity Bs onCreate() you store that boolean value for later use.
In activity Bs onBackPressed() you can check the value of your boolean and if true, launch activity A before calling finish();

A prettier solution may be to launch activity A from the notification, with an extra telling it to directly launch activity B.